Dual Monitor - Gdm3 logging screen is splitted into 2
Is it possible to temporarily disable the 2nd monitor while logging in?
On boot, gdm3 splits my logging screen into 2. I can't even find the box to enter the password.
I use xrandr --output DP-2 --auto but its effect reset after resetting the laptop.
